# Issue running simple hello world in PUG

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Guys I have problems running a simple example with PUG.
I installed it (have it in dependencies). Here is code how I use it

```
app.get('/users/:id',function (req, res) {

    var user = userDatabase.find(req.params.id); 
    // user is well defined here
    pug.renderFile('userdetails.pug', {
        id:user.id,
        name: user.name,
        lastname:user.surname
    });

});
```

Here is require

```
const pug = require('pug');
```

The userdetails.pug file is located in the same directory as the index.js file which contains above function.

Here is pug file:

```
h1 User Details
p ID: #{id}
p name: #{name}
p surname: #{lastname}
```

But when I hit that address with get, browser hangs.
Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

stupid me, I fixed it had to send result of render to browser back using send.